# Asking for help on correct way to us SQL with CTE to create JSON_OBJECT

Tags: sql, json, db2, rpgle

The requested JSON needs to be in this form:

```
{
    "header": {
        "InstanceName": "US"
    },
    "erpReferenceData": {
        "erpReferences": [
            {
                "ServiceID": "fb16e421-792b-4e9c-935b-3cea04a84507",
                "ERPReferenceID": "J0000755"
            },
            {
                "ServiceID": "7d13d907-0932-44c0-ad81-600c9b97b6e5",
                "ERPReferenceID": "J0000756"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The program that I created looks like this:

```
dcl-s OutFile sqltype(dbclob_file);  

exec sql                                                 
 With x as (                                             
 select  json_object(                                    
 'InstanceName' : trim(Cntry)   ) objHeader                     
 from xmlhdr                                   
 where cntry = 'US'),                                    
                                                         
 y as (                                                  
 select  json_object(                                    
      'ServiceID' VALUE S.ServiceID,                     
      'ERPReferenceID' VALUE I.RefCod) oOjRef      
 FROM IMH I                                           
   INNER JOIN GUIDS G ON G.REFCOD = I.REFCOD 
   INNER JOIN SERV S ON S.GUID = G.GUID               
  WHERE G.XMLTYPE = 'Service')                           
                                                         
   VALUES   (                                            
  select json_object('header'  : objHeader Format json , 
    'erpReferenceData' : json_object(                    
                     'erpReferences' VALUE               
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(               
          ObjRef Format json)))    
       from x                      
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  y ON 1=1       
  Group by objHeader)              
     INTO  :OutFile;
```

This is the compile error I get:

> SQL0122: Position 41 Column OBJHEADER or expression in SELECT list not valid.

I am asking if this is the correct way to create this SQL statement, is there a better easier way?  Any idea how to rewrite the SQL statement to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key with generating JSON or XML for that matter is to start from the inside and work your way out.

(I've simplified the raw data into just a test table...)

```
with elm as(select json_object 
                   ('ServiceID' VALUE ServiceID,                     
                   'ERPReferenceID' VALUE RefCod) as erpRef
            from jsontst)
select * from elm;
```

Now add the next layer as a CTE the builds on the first CTE..

```
with elm as(select json_object 
                   ('ServiceID' VALUE ServiceID,                     
                   'ERPReferenceID' VALUE RefCod) as erpRef
            from jsontst)
 , arr (arrDta) as (values json_array (select erpRef from elm)) 
select * from arr;
```

And the next layer...

```
with elm as(select json_object 
                   ('ServiceID' VALUE ServiceID,                     
                   'ERPReferenceID' VALUE RefCod) as erpRef
            from jsontst)
 , arr (arrDta) as (values json_array (select erpRef from elm)) 
 , erpReferences (refs) as ( select json_object 
                                 ('erpReferences' value arrDta )
                            from arr)
select * 
from erpReferences;
```

Nice thing about building with CTE's is at each step, you can see the results so far...

You can actually always go back and stick a `Select * from CTE;` in the middle to see what you have at some point.

Note that I'm building this in Run SQL Scripts.  Once you have the statement complete, you can embed it in your RPG program.

Comment: thank you so much for breaking this out the way you did.  I have been learning from your example and trying to change it to what I need.  I have additional questions.
From the JSON that is being created, and it looks like it is putting the “erpReferences” as a string.  I have tried to add the “format JSON” to fix this, but I have not been able to get this to work in any place I have tried.

Comment: one additional question.  How do I have the JSON create both the erpReferenceData and the header information into the same JSON?  I can get one or the other, but not both to fall under the same outer JSON {brackets}.

Comment: @JohnBaeten your going to want to use `JSON_OBJECT ('header' value <xxx>, 'erpReferenceData' value <xxx>)` in your final select.  The prior CTE would likly have two columns...sorry I don't have any additional time to play with it today...

Comment: I do have the SQL to create the JSON working, but is there any reason when using a CTE inside of the SQLRPGLE program we would get an SQLCOD of -101, which is the statement is too long or too complex.  The SQL statement is small, do you know of anything that needs to be turned on our system to allow the CTE’s to work with JSON?  We are using CTE’s in other programs much more complicated than this, and they have no issues.

Comment: @JohnBaeten nope.  Is this run-time or compile time?  I'd suggest posting a new question with the current RPG code.

Comment: It is at run time, I will create a new post.  Thank you for all of your help, the info you gave did get me to create the JSON correctly, just need to get this next step now.